# How to display exact numbers, and not abbreviations, in Grafana?

Tags: data-visualization, grafana, graph-visualization

I have a graph in Grafana that gives a total count.

[image: Total Recordings' Count]

I'm trying to find a way that when the cursor hovers above a data-point

[image: cursor hovers above a data-point]

I won't see the value as *9.96 Mil*, but as the actual exact decimal number.

Is there a way to do that in Grafana (v7.5.7)?

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Unit" in the panel option, "none" will show the actual exact number:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Marcelo. 
Your suggestion changes the numbers' display throughout the graph, and also when the cursor hovers above a data point. Is there a way to leave the graph Y-axis scale as `short`, but have the cursor hovering display using the `none` format?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

In the options section under `Axes`, you can set `Decimals` to the number of decimals you want to have displayed.